# How to parse HTMLDocument using java7's org.w3c.dom.html package instead of Jsoup?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup, w3c

In my project I was using jsoup to parse html documents and to process them but now I came to know that java 7 has w3c org.w3c.dom.html which can be used to process html documents, but no tutorial or other helping contents are available for that so please help me in finding alternate of this jsoup code

```
    File in = new File("index.html");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(in, null);
    Element form = doc.select("form").first();
    Elements in=doc.getElementsByTag("input");
    for(Element el:in){
        el.attr("value", "23");
    }
```

Jsoup is the only externel package in my project so I want to replace that with java7's existing features.

Answer (score 0):

JSoup is great - why are you trying to replace it?

EDIT:

Maybe this will help:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-wkdom/index.html

Comment: This is my college project and I want to avoid any external library in this, that's why I am trying to do the same thing the above code does with w3c org.w3c.dom.html HTMLDocument, I just need the alternate code for that because nowhere on internet I can find this code for w3c package.

Comment: That link is not helping because there they used 
// Docuverse imports
import com.docuverse.dom.DOM;
import com.docuverse.dom.html.HTMLFactory;

which is also external library